# R building a dynamic list based off grouping of a column and values of other applicable columns

Tags: r, list

I am currently working in R and am attempting to create dynamic lists. I have a data table that contains values for the following columns - study_site, anthro, modnum, and list_val. Each study site value has varying combinations of anthro, modnum, and list_val.

I want to take the following code and make it so the lists are building dynamically as opposed to having to hardcode each study name and anthro value into an if statement as each study_site value does not have every type of anthro value (stunt, uwei, and waste) but some do. Additionally, not all study_site values have all modnum values (1-5), but each hold combinations of some of the 5.

The list_val column in the data table corresponds to the first part of each item in the list and the second portion on the right side of the = sign can be pulled from anthro and modnum values in the same table

(i.e. where list_val==paste0("lmod_",anthro,modnum)

```
if(y=="one"){
  if(anthro=="stunt") 
  {l <- list(lstunt1 = lmod_stunt1, lstunt3 = lmod_stunt3, lstunt4 = lmod_stunt4, lstunt5 = lmod_stunt5)} 
  if(anthro=="uwei") 
  {l <- list(luwei1 = lmod_uwei1, luwei3 = lmod_uwei3, luwei4 = lmod_uwei4, luwei5 = lmod_uwei5)} 
  if(anthro=="waste") 
  {l <- list(lwaste1 = lmod_waste1, lwaste3 = lmod_waste3, lwaste4 = lmod_waste4, lwaste5 = lmod_waste5)} 
}
```

Here's a small snippet of the data table for a quick view:

```
study_site   anthro   modnum  list_val
four         stunt    1       lstunt1
four         stunt    3       lstunt3
four         stunt    4       lstunt4
four         stunt    5       lstunt5
four         uwei     1       luwei1
four         uwei     3       luwei3
four         uwei     4       luwei4
four         uwei     5       luwei5
four         waste    1       lwaste1
four         waste    3       lwaste3
four         waste    4       lwaste4
four         waste    5       lwaste5
```

I know I would likely have to group by the study_site and anthro values, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this step or the steps that would follow. Is it possible to build these lists dynamically?

Here is the dput value of a part of the original table:

```
structure(list(study_site = c("one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "three", "three", 
"three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", 
"three", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", 
"four", "four", "four", "four", "four"), anthro = c("stunt", 
"stunt", "stunt", "stunt", "stunt", "uwei", "uwei", "uwei", "uwei", 
"uwei", "waste", "waste", "waste", "waste", "waste", "stunt", 
"stunt", "stunt", "stunt", "stunt", "uwei", "uwei", "uwei", "uwei", 
"uwei", "waste", "waste", "waste", "waste", "waste", "stunt", 
"stunt", "stunt", "stunt", "uwei", "uwei", "uwei", "waste", "waste", 
"waste", "stunt", "stunt", "stunt", "stunt", "uwei", "uwei", 
"uwei", "uwei", "waste", "waste", "waste", "waste"), modnum = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 
5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5), poisson_model = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), list_val = c("lstunt1", "lstunt2", "lstunt3", 
"lstunt4", "lstunt5", "luwei1", "luwei2", "luwei3", "luwei4", 
"luwei5", "lwaste1", "lwaste2", "lwaste3", "lwaste4", "lwaste5", 
"lstunt1", "lstunt2", "lstunt3", "lstunt4", "lstunt5", "luwei1", 
"luwei2", "luwei3", "luwei4", "luwei5", "lwaste1", "lwaste2", 
"lwaste3", "lwaste4", "lwaste5", "lstunt1", "lstunt2", "lstunt3", 
"lstunt4", "luwei2", "luwei3", "luwei4", "lwaste2", "lwaste3", 
"lwaste4", "lstunt1", "lstunt3", "lstunt4", "lstunt5", "luwei1", 
"luwei3", "luwei4", "luwei5", "lwaste1", "lwaste3", "lwaste4", 
"lwaste5")), row.names = c(NA, -52L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: What is `lmod_stunt1` ? Can you show how your expected output would look?

Comment: lmod_stunt1 and the other varying combinations of anthro and modnum each point to a model. The combinations of models ran for each study need to be stored as a list

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `expand.grid`?

```
d <- transform(expand.grid(study_site=c("one", "two", "three", "four"),
                           anthro=c("stunt", "uwei", "waste"),
                           modnum=1:5,
                           poisson_model=1),
               list_val=Reduce(paste0, cbind("l", d[c("anthro", "modnum")])))
d <- d[order(d$study_site, d$anthro, d$modnum), ]
head(d)
#    study_site anthro modnum poisson_model list_val
# 1         one  stunt      1             1  lstunt1
# 13        one  stunt      2             1  lstunt2
# 25        one  stunt      3             1  lstunt3
# 37        one  stunt      4             1  lstunt4
# 49        one  stunt      5             1  lstunt5
# 5         one   uwei      1             1   luwei1
```

Comment: Not quite. I am looking to create lists dynamically for each study that contain the combination of anthro and modnum available, like the following : l <- list(lstunt1 = lmod_stunt1, lstunt3 = lmod_stunt3, lstunt4 = lmod_stunt4, lstunt5 = lmod_stunt5)